# GetJson with WebWorker

Tags: javascript

How can I make my Script working with WebWorker

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {  
                    var x="";  
                        for (i=0;i<data.sturi.length;i++)
                        {
                         $("#stdjgls ul").append("<li itemid="+i+"><a href=#vl>"+data.sturi[i]+"</a></li>");
                         stdge[i]=data.sturi[i];

                        }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use a web worker for that.

Comment: is that not necessary for a page which will be available per smartphone, when one has a bad connection ??

Comment: No; web workers are just for blocking (CPU-bound) work.

Comment: but when there is a connection lost does the cpu block, because there is no data available??

Comment: No; that's what **asynchronous** means.

Comment: i think the webworker should not access to DOM

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an instance of WebWorker beforehand. Also, declare the stgde just in case.

```
var worker = new Worker('/js/mywebworker.js');
var stgde=[];
```

then declare a listener for the Webworker messages to perform something.

```
worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    do something with e... 
}, false);
```

Then, inside the getJSON, pass the `data` variable to the webworker as message.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {  
    var x="";  
    worker.postMessage(data);
}
```

Provided that your webworker is able to interact with the DOM (which isn't possible, but let's ignore that), it would append the `<li>` items and return stdge as a result. In that case, the listener function you declared would be

```
worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    stdge=e.data;
    worker.terminate();
}, false);
```

I don't know why are you using a WebWorker to do this, but as a proof of concept it would work.

It could theoretically help you offload the burden of iterating through the data array, but that's negligible. **The dom manipulation, in fact, won't work**, so you wouldn't be able to insert the li elements. This means you need to do it in the listener function.

```
worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    stdge=e.data;
    for (var i=0;i<stdge.length;i++) {
        $("#stdjgls ul").append("<li itemid="+i+"><a href=#vl>"+stdge[i]+"</a></li>");
    }
    worker.terminate();
}, false);
```

TD / LR

you're creating a new thread to iterate through a shallow array. That's just plain overkill.